# How to look through two lists and if one entry in one list matches and entry in another, use the other, if not, keep using the first list?

Tags: python, list

I'm messing around with Python and how that might apply to stock trading.

For particular stocks in particular quarters I have assigned a value to it that helps me decide if I like the stock or not.  These values are in a list called "B."  I have another list that has all of the quarters for the same stock called release dates.

How do I create a script that looks at the releasedates list and if there is a value in B list for a particular quarter, use the value from the B list, if not, use a value of zero?

I've tried this

```
release dates = [...(AAPL, 1, 2010), (AAPL, 2, 2010), (AAPL, 3, 2010), (AAPL, 4, 2010)...]

B = [(AAPL, 1, 2010, 2), (AAPL, 4, 2010, 10)]

output = []
for ticker, quarter, year, in releasedates:
    value_2 = 0
    for ticker_2, quarter_2, year_2, value in B:
        if (ticker_2 == ticker and year_2 == year and quarter_2 == quarter):
        output.append((ticker, quarter, year, value))   
    output.append((ticker, quarter, year, outside, value_2))
```

But this gives me both the B list values and a value of 0 in two separate tuples for each date.  Something like this:

(The format is ticker, quarter, year, value)

[...
(AAPL, 3, 2015, 10),
(AAPL, 3, 2015, 0)
(AAPL, 4, 2015, 0)
...]

When what I really want is this:

[...
(AAPL, 3, 2015, 10),
(AAPL, 4, 2015, 0)
...]

Comment: could you provide a [mcve] ? shouldn't be too hard, but currently it's a little unclear. Provide expected & current output as well.

Comment: Your example doesn't have a `B` ... what does that look like? You seem to have two lists with the same things in them. Which is which?

Comment: @tdelaney....sorry, the latest_buys is my B list.  Thanks. edited.

Comment: @wpercy Yes, sorry, edited.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  I will improve it.

Comment: You still haven't shown us what B looks like. Is it just `(ticker,quarter,year)` for the stock quarters you like?

Comment: @tdelaney - edited.  it is (ticker, quarter, year, value)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using example data as you did not give any examples of your own. If you used a dictionary where the key was a certain stock, and the value was some sort of flag, you could do the following (*O(n) speed complexity*):

```
B = {1: True, 4: True}  # Example flags. True being a good stock in this example.
releases = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  # Example stocks.
for stock_id in releases:
    if B.get(stock_id):
        # Do Something
```

Other wise, loop over `B` inside of `releases`:

```
B = [(2, True), (4, True)]
releases = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for stock in releases:
    for flag in B:
        if stock == flag[0]:
            # Do Something, you've found a good stock.
```

Better yet, use some Object-oriented design and make a stock object (example below).

```
class Stock(object):
   def __init__(self, id, name, price, is_good):
       self.id = id
       self.name = name
       self.price = price
       self.is_good = is_good
```

This way, you don't need parallelized data containers to compare values; the data to determine a good stock is fully encapsulated in the `Stock` object itself.

Now we can see how much cleaner and efficient a potential loop could look (*no more indexing or accessing of other containers, just a simple member access*).

```
for stock in stocks:
   if stock.is_good:
       # enter code here
```

Comment: Trying to think of how your second idea is different than what I'm doing?  I will try to do your first idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure of the specific of your data, it's impossible for me to debug your issue without access of your input (*but they do look similar*).

Answer (score 1):

You can index `B` by `ticker, quarter, year` using a dictionary and then the lookup is easy

```
releasedates = [('AAPL', 1, 2010), ('AAPL', 2, 2010), ('AAPL', 3, 2010), 
    ('AAPL', 4, 2010)]
B = [('AAPL', 1, 2010, 2), ('AAPL', 4, 2010, 10)]
# index wanted values
B_index = {item[:3]:item[3] for item in B}
output = [(ticker, quarter, year, B_index.get((ticker, quarter, year), 0))
    for ticker, quarter, year in releasedates]
print(output)
```

Comment: It looks like this worked and was super easy!  Thanks.